# Canvas fillText : display numbers progressively

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've made a program to draw on a web page (like the Turtle in Logo).

The code for drawing animated lines is for example :
    var liste_mouvements = [];
    var en_mouvement = false;
    var en_couleur = false ;
    var ecrit = false ;
    var timer;

```
function avancer(distance){
liste_mouvements.push(function(){
var iter = 1 ;

en_mouvement = true;
var compteur = 1 ;
timer = setInterval(function() {
    var Angle = angle % 360 ;
    var theta = Angle/180*Math.PI ;
    if (ecrit) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        x = Math.cos(theta)*distance/vitesse + x ;
        y = Math.sin(theta)*distance/vitesse + y ; 
        ctx.lineTo(x,y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    else {
        x = Math.cos(theta)*distance/vitesse + x ;
        y = Math.sin(theta)*distance/vitesse + y ; 
    }  
    compteur++;
    if(compteur>vitesse){
        clearInterval(timer);
        en_mouvement = false;
        prochain_mouvement();
    }
},
duree/vitesse);
 });
  prochain_mouvement();
}

function prochain_mouvement() {
    if (!en_mouvement && !en_couleur && !changement_taille && liste_mouvements.length) {
        var mouvement = liste_mouvements.shift() ;
        mouvement();
}
} 
function AFFICHER_TEXTE(txt,x_txt,y_txt) {
liste_mouvements.push(function() {
    changement_taille = true ;
    en_couleur = true ;
    en_mouvement = true ;
    ctx.fillText(txt,x_txt,y_txt);
    changement_taille = false ;
    en_couleur = false ;
    en_mouvement = false ;
    prochain_mouvement();
});
}
```

I can make a grid, which appears progressively (with function avancer() and other functions), and I want to fill the grid with numbers, which appear progressively too, but the numbers are displayed together.

How can I change my function AFFICHER_TEXTE() to do this ?

I have an other problem. I have a function to save the image :

```
function SAUVER_IMAGE(fileName) {
liste_mouvements.push(function() {
var Nom_Image = prompt("Nom de l'image", "Tortue");
if(Nom_Image==null){
    Nom_Image = "Tortue";
}
Nom_Image = Nom_Image + ".png";
var canvasElement = document.getElementById("dessin");

var MIME_TYPE = "image/png";

var image_URL = canvasElement.toDataURL(MIME_TYPE);

var Lien_Telechargement = document.createElement('a');
Lien_Telechargement.download = Nom_Image;
Lien_Telechargement.href = image_URL;
Lien_Telechargement.dataset.downloadurl = [MIME_TYPE, Lien_Telechargement.download, Lien_Telechargement.href].join(':');

document.body.appendChild(Lien_Telechargement);
Lien_Telechargement.click();
document.body.removeChild(Lien_Telechargement);
prochain_mouvement();
}); 
}
```

With Firefox, the function to save image is called after the text is displayed with AFFICHER_TEXTE(), but with CHROME the SAUVER_IMAGE() function is called before, and the image I save is not complete. How can I fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hello! Could you provide the whole code? Some functions (AFFICHER_TEXTE, mouvement, ...) aren't not displayed and it could be helpful to have them (for instance to make a working example). In your grid example, your grid appears progressively but the numbers inside appear suddenly, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the numbers appear suddenly.

The functions AFFICHER_TEXTE() and prochain_mouvement are written in the first part of code.

To write code in comments I put the code between ' ' ?